# A word for this kind of intimate action

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

When somebody touches you in some sensitive areas of your body, like armpits, "it will make you laugh in some kind of way".

When you want to tell somebody that you are not going to touch them in that way, you can't say "I won't make you laugh again".

What is the proper expression to use instead ?

Comment: Tickle? sdf sdf sdf

Comment: Notice that I found it googling "armpit touch laugh"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reframed the question a little, without changing the meaning.

The word you are looking for is **tickle**.

---

When you want to tell somebody that you are not going to touch them in that way, you can say **"I won't tickle you"**.